# Nginx auth for all but one subroute in a location

Tags: nginx

Disclaimer: Im not close with nginx

I had this location block inside my server:

```
location /appname/ {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:11399/;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real_IP $remote_addr;
}
```

I want to set basic auth on every page except for `/appname/`.
So if path is `/appname/` then just pass this to the docker container on 11399 port. But if path is anything else (`^/appname/.+`) then ask to auth before.

Important! I can not edit outer server block since it contains tons of other apps on other locations and I need this to apply only to this location block.

I tried this:

```
location = /appname/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:11399/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real_IP $remote_addr;
}
location ~ ^/appname/(.+)$ {
    auth_basic "Hello hiiii";
    auth_basic_user_file /path/to/.htpasswd;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:11399/$1;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real_IP $remote_addr;
}
```

It made sense to me, if the path is `/appname/` then go to `location = /appname/` block. If not, go to regex block. But when I access `myhost.com/appname/` I get prompted with auth form for some reason. It doesnt make sense, not in any world `/appname/` matches `^/appname/.+` regex expression. Looks like something goes behind the nginx's curtains that I am not aware of.

I will also appreciate a lot if someone can suggest me a way to make this work using one location block with nested ones. I dont like that prev example has duplicate lines. I tried something like this

```
location /appname/ {
    auth_basic "Hello hiiii";
    auth_basic_user_file /path/to/.htpasswd;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:11399/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real_IP $remote_addr;
    location = /appname/ {
        auth_basic off;
    }
}
```

And a lot of it's variants but none worked. Mostly it gave 404 when accessing `/appname/`

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [the nginx auth basic docs](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-http-basic-authentication/)!
Try to use "auth_basic off;" and "allow all".
I have a suspicion that there may be an additional issue at play.

try this:

```
location /appname/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:11399/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real_IP $remote_addr;
    allow all;
    auth_basic off;
}
```